# How to change Symfony 1.x message for secure module

Tags: symfony1

I'm looking for a way how to change default message saying that login is required to see a page created in secure module. Currently it look like this: https://gyazo.com/1477f388deb20e4da3e13c5a957e86ce

Do you know how to change it or create a redirect to a different route ?

Currently I'm using symfony 1.19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

- login_module and login_action: Action called when a nonauthenticated user tries to access a page defined as secure in security.yml. The default value is default/login.
- secure_module and secure_action: Action called when a user doesn't have the credentials required for an action. The default value is default/secure.

You can override the default pages in two ways:

- You can create your own default module in the application's modules/ directory, override all the actions defined in the settings.yml file (index, error404, login, secure, disabled) and all the related templates (indexSuccess.php, error404Success.php, loginSuccess.php, secureSuccess.php, disabledSuccess.php).
- You can change the default module and action settings of the settings.yml file to use pages of your application.